# Enhanced letterhead - new button

Tags: email-template, salesforce-support, letterhead

I am not able to see button in Enhanced letterhead in salesforce.
Can any one give me the solution on how to enable the new button[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the "New" button under Enhanced letterhead, you have to enable the "Modify All Data" permission on the user profile.

See [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_letterheads_create.htm&type=5)

Also, make sure you have this perm enabled on clickpath:
`Profile | System Permission | Manage Letterheads- Create, edit, and delete letterheads for HTML emails`

.

Comment: It works. Thankyou!